# GitHub Actions: how to target all branches EXCEPT master?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I want to be able to let an action run on any given branch except master.
I am aware that there is a prebuilt `filter` action, but I want the exact opposite.

More like GitLab's `except` keyword. 
Since this is not inside the official docs, has anyone prepared a decent workaround?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Their documentation seems to imply that you might be able to do this using something like:
`on: 
  push:
    branches:    
      - '!master'`
https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on

But I haven't been able to get similar negated patterns to work.

Comment: Thank you Ollie, sadly this doesn't seem to trigger the pipeline...

Answer (score 210, accepted):

**Update**:
There is a newer filter described in [Samy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62918562/2082842) that provides a more succinct way of achieving this.

---

[The documentation](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#on) has been updated with more information now:

> When you specify a `branches` or `tags` filter, **the workflow only runs if at least one pattern matches**. Any changes to branches or tags that don't match a defined pattern will not trigger a workflow. The order that you define patterns matters:

- A matching negative pattern after a positive match will exclude the
  ref again.
- A matching positive pattern after a negative match will
  include the ref again.

So in order to exclude `master`, you need to ensure that a pattern matching everything is included first:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:    
      - '*'         # matches every branch that doesn't contain a '/'
      - '*/*'       # matches every branch containing a single '/'
      - '**'        # matches every branch
      - '!master'   # excludes master
```

Comment: \*/\* only matches branches containing exactly one /

Comment: @ wrymug Thanks, that was what i meant - I will edit the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for updating. It’s too bad GitHub Actions doesn’t seem to provide a true wildcard pattern.

Comment: @wrymug and others not sure if this is a new feature or not, but `'**'` will match every branch. See [the docs](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet) for more info.

Answer (score 160):

There is now a [`branches-ignore`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestbranchestags) option:

```
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - master
```

Note that you cannot use `branches-ignore` and `branches` in the same workflow.

Comment: branches-ignore is not working for me. 

`on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - release
  pull_request:
    branches-ignore:
      - release
`

Comment: @Vaulstein `branches-ignore` and `branches` cannot use at the same time on a event.

Comment: @JSKIM that is not the same event, though - `branches` is used on `push` and `branches-ignore` on `pull_request`. That should work, shouldn't it?