# Use environment variable in github action if

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to use an environment variable in an `if` condition in github actions like so:

```
name: Worfklow
on:
  push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1

      - name: EXIT step
        if: $GITHUB_REF == 'specific-branch'
        run: exit 1
```

I want to exit if the current branch is equal to a specific branch.

Unfortunately, the github actions console displays an error:

```
Unexpected symbol: '$GITHUB_REF'
```

I can use `$GITHUB_REF` in a `run:` (where it contains the current branch), but not in an `if:`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

do it like this:

```
if: github.ref == 'specific-branch'
```

reference [branch conditional](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/GitHub-Actions-branch-conditional/td-p/29794)

Comment: A word of warning: github.ref will store either the current branch or tag ref. This depends on the action that caused the workflow. Source: https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contexts

Comment: This does not answer the actual question asked though which is how to access an environmental variable from `if:`... how is this done if it's truly an environnmental variable and not something you can just go fetch from the magic `github` context?

Answer (score 56):

Though the original problem had been solved without environment vars, I'd like to share how it can be used with if conditions.

```yaml
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Set env BRANCH
        run: echo "BRANCH=$(echo $GITHUB_REF | cut -d'/' -f 3)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Set env NEED
        run: |
          if [[ $BRANCH == 'master' && $GITHUB_EVENT_NAME == 'push' ]]; then
              echo "NEED=true" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          else
              echo "NEED=false" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
          fi

      - name: Skip Deploy?
        if: env.NEED != 'true'
        run: echo "Only pushing to 'master' causes automatic deployment"

     ...
```

The first two steps set 2 env variables, the third step demonstrates what syntax you need to follow to use these vars in if conditions.

Comment: This solution works for any environment variable needed on any step, which is more complete than other solutions. This is why I think it should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but it could be clearer. The point being: Use `env.MYVAR` instead of `$MYVAR`.

Comment: for more info on environment variables: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables

Comment: I needed to use secrets in if statements: `if: ${{ env.super_secret != '' }}` https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-secrets

Comment: You can only use the env variables you set on the next step, not in the same step

Comment: `if: env.NEED == 'true' gives me an invalid workflow file: Unrecognized named-value: 'env'. Located at position 1 within expression: env.VALID_LABELS == 'true'

Comment: ^As I've later learned that `env` is not available in the `jobs.<job_id>.if` context.  

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check an environment variable on job-level (refer to Github [context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts)), you can do like this:

```
env:
  MY_VAR: Dummy

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest         
    outputs:
      myVar: ${{ steps.init.outputs.myVar }}
    
    steps:        
      - name: Environment variables to output 
        id: init
        run: |
          echo "myVar=${{ env.MY_VAR }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

And use it in another job:

```
  second_job:
    name: Second Job
    needs: build
    if: needs.build.outputs.myVar == 'Dummy'
```

Comment: sad one can't use the env variable directly without all that overhead...in my case, I just wanted to pull a condition into an env var, but it's not worth it with that solution.

Comment: @MarianKlühspies It's by design. Maybe GitHub changes it in the future.. :)

Comment: This has worked for me, thanks @BakedInhalf  There's further explanation in the docs: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/defining-outputs-for-jobs

Answer (score 0):

As @Claudio noted, the solution is to use `env.MYVAR`. For reference, I am sharing [an example from my own use case](https://github.com/maciejskorski/plantuml-docker/actions/runs/4657190397): the presence of GitHub secrets will trigger docker publishing.

```
name: docker-image

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
    paths: ["Dockerfile",".github/workflows/docker-image.yaml"]
  workflow_dispatch:


jobs:
  build-and-publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Docker tags and credentials for DockerHub/GitHub Containers, customize!
    env:
      IMAGE_NAME: plantuml-docker
      IMAGE_VERSION: latest
      DOCKER_USER: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USER }}
      DOCKER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
      GITHUB_USER: ${{ github.actor }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Build and tag the image
      run: |
        docker build . \
        --tag $DOCKER_USER/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION \
        --tag ghcr.io/$GITHUB_USER/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION
    - name: Publish to DockerHub
      if: env.DOCKER_PASSWORD != ''
      run: |
        docker login -u $DOCKER_USER -p $DOCKER_PASSWORD
        docker push $DOCKER_USER/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION
    - name: Publish to GitHub Container registry
      if: env.GITHUB_TOKEN != ''
      run: |
        docker login ghcr.io -u $GITHUB_USER -p $GITHUB_TOKEN 
        docker push ghcr.io/$GITHUB_USER/$IMAGE_NAME:$IMAGE_VERSION
```

Answer (score -6):

You can use some restrictions on the push section of the action

```
on:
  push:
    branches:    
      - '*'         # matches every branch that doesn't contain a '/'
      - '*/*'       # matches every branch containing a single '/'
      - '**'        # matches every branch
      - '!master'   # excludes master
```

This answer was taken from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57699839/github-actions-how-to-target-all-branches-except-master)