# Unexpected expression results from if condition

Tags: github-actions

So i have a workflow with multiple jobs and environment variables. For example one variable called `BRANCH` and it's value `${{ github.ref }}` .

The workflow has multiple jobs and each with a condition:

```
development:
name: Deploy to dev
needs: build
if: ${{ needs.build.outputs.environment == 'dev' }}
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

This works fine for each job, but as soon as I apply a second condition unexpected things happens..

```
development:
name: Deploy to dev
needs: build
if: ${{ needs.build.outputs.environment == 'dev' }} && env.BRANCH == 'loreem ipsum'
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

This always resolvs to `true`, tested echo it out like:

```
echo ${{ needs.build.outputs.environment == 'dev' }} && env.BRANCH == 'loreem ipsum'
```

My initial guess is that it resolvs to `<if expression> && true || false` But writing like below will not work, as 'env' is unknown to job.if.

```
if: ${{ needs.build.outputs.environment == 'dev' && env.BRANCH == 'loreem ipsum' }}
```

I even tried with

```
if: ${{ needs.build.outputs.environment == 'dev' }} && ${{ env.BRANCH == 'loreem ipsum' }}
```

So is this expected or is my syntax incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#failure-with-conditions) the correct way to use the `&&` expression is,

```
if: ${{ needs.build.outputs.environment == 'dev' && env.BRANCH == 'loreem ipsum' }}
```

But you might be getting an error saying that `env` is not available under `jobs.development.if`. This is because only following contexts are  available under  `jobs.<job_id>.if`.

```
github, needs, inputs
```

See [context availability](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability) table for more information.

So the solution is to use the `github` context(as it's available under `jobs.<job_id>.if`) and access `github.ref` direclty to perform the branch comparison.

```
if: ${{ needs.build.outputs.environment == 'dev' && github.ref == 'loreem ipsum' }}
```

Comment: Docs says ```&&``` is an AND operator. So since env is not in context the solution would be to output in another step and use it with ```needs```. Branch was just an example of an environment variable

Comment: @BakedInhalf If that is the case [this will](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67049122/6699447) helps