# Trigger GitHub Actions for all branches except main, where the only workflow definition file is

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to build a repository which allows me to build Docker images for different versions of a project I'm forking.
The repo should have the following layout:

- `main` branch where the workflow is defined, with a trigger such as:

  ```yaml
  on:
     push:
       branches-ignore:
         - main
  ```

  The workflow builds the software from any branch (basically a `mvn clean package`, `docker build` and `docker push` that applies to all versions of the software)
- many `software-1.2.3` branches which don't contain any `.github/workflow` files (it would be cumbersome to copy this file into each branch, and maintain it there)

From my research so far, it seems that GitHub Actions only runs when a workflow definition is present. However, I wonder if there's a way using webhooks or something to trick the system into doing what I want.

My next best option would probably be using [workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch),

Comment: If you have the workflow in `main` and then create new branches, all the branches contain the workflow, no?

Comment: No, the branches are not forked off from `main`. They are forks from an external repository.
Here's an example: https://github.com/rmetzger/flink-docker-factory. I would like to run the workflow defined in `master` on every push to `flink-1.13` (or similar branches).

Comment: I don't think I understand your workflow, I'm afraid.

Comment: If you don't need it to be realtime, you can consider using the [cron](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#scheduled-events) features, and detect branches that have been added to the repo, check via Github API if a workflow exists for their last commit, and if not, trigger one.

This wouldn't be trivial.

Maybe you could add a commit on top of each of the external branches with the wanted workflow?

Comment: This looks promising:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57903434/7453391

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it requires a workflow definition to be present in each branch to trigger a build.

Comment: You are correct in assuming that github actions runs when a workflow is present in the branch. Basically pushing workflow files to all branches is a little cumbersome, but having the workflows only defined in the main branch and using workflow dispatch would mean that the workflow in main would need to checkout code from other branches, making it even more cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

`on: push !main` wouldn't work, because that !main branch would need to have this workflow in it.

Running the workflow manually is the easiest solution to implement.

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      BRANCH_OF_FORK:
        description: 'branch name, on which this pipeline should run'
        required: true
jobs:
  doSomething:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.BRANCH_OF_FORK }}

      - run: docker build something something
```

There's a `on:fork` event, that could be used to trigger a run, but it could only trigger a fork event of this specific branch, that has the `on:fork` code in it's workflow.

It's possible to run the workflow on a cron job without on-fork event, but you would have to pick the correct branch programmatically.

```yaml
steps:
 - id: branch-selector
   run: |
     git clone ${{ github.event.repo.url }} .

     all_branches=`git branch --all | grep -v " main\$" | grep -v "/main\$"`
     correct_branch=`pick_correct_branch.py $all_branches`
     git checkout -b $correct_branch

  - run: docker build something something
```

`pick_correct_branch.py` is left as an exercise for the reader to implement.